# How do I set a precedence value to operators such as '*', '/', '+', and '-.

Tags: c++

I either want to set them to bool values or simply integer values so that I can tell my function to multiply/divide these two integers before I add/subtract them to another operand.

Here is my code:

```
while (!S.empty() && **PRECEDENCE**next <= **PRECEDENCE**S.top())
{
    temp = S.top();
    S.pop();
    postfix.append(temp);
}
```

Where `S` is for the stack. So let's say `next` is the `*` token and `S.top()` is '`+`', so `*` takes priority over `+`, so I need to assign a value to `*` and `+` so that when they are compared to one another, their values are compared. So the value of `*` is `1` whereas the value of `+` is `0`.

Comment: What types do the contents of your container `S` have? You need to show some more code if we're going to have a chance at helping...

Comment: Nope. Didn't get that.

Comment: Precedence is not variable in C++, if you mean that. Use parentheses to override.

Comment: Just write a function `int GetPrecedence(char)` that returns 1 for '*' and '/'. Returns 0 for '+' and '-'.

Answer (score 1):

OMG, there are many methods to do this.

**Look up table**
You could create a table of  records and search the table for the operator, then retrieve the precedence value.

**Use switch statement**
I don't advise, but it is similar functionality of *mapping* a precedence to an operator.

**Use `std::map`**
Same concept as the other two, except using `std::map<char, int>` for operator character and precedence.

**Hard code the precedence**
The operators you compare for first will have the highest precedence.  The next operators checked will have lower precedence.

**Search the Web and StackOverflow**
Hint:  Other people have done this assignment.  Search StackOverflow or the web for:

```
"c++ postfix operator precedence"
"c++ calculator operator precedence"
"c++ calculator operator evaluation"
"c++ postfix operator evaluation"
```

Or use other synonyms that I haven't listed.

**Research before posting**
Be as smart person and cheat by researching and seeing what other people have done.  Before posting questions here.

**Use a debugger**
Use a debugger or print statements to see where your issues lie.
If you are still stumped, post the issue, your minimal code and the expected behavior.